# SQL / MySQL: Sum all amounts for respective month

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table in my database which looks like this:

```
payment_id          customer_id         amount          payment_date            
1                   32                  20.00           2005-01-25 11:30:37
2                   32                  10.00           2005-01-26 11:30:37
3                   11                  25.00           2005-03-25 11:30:37
```

Now I want to sum all amounts a customer (customer_id) made in the respective month.
I need a query that looks which month exists and which customers have an entry for this month.

The result should look like this:

```
customer_id         month           amount
32                  01              30.00
11                  03              25
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT month(payment_date) AS month, customer_id, sum(amount) AS amount
FROM table
```

But it just sums all amount values of the whole table.

Comment: You need to use `group by` and then sum up the amounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a GROUP BY query:

```
SELECT
  customer_id,
  month(payment_date) as month,
  sum(amount) as total_amount
FROM
  tablename
GROUP BY
  customer_id,
  month(payment_date)
```

Comment: This works just fine, thank you very much. I need to take a closer look at "Group By".